# DRF - Relative URL with ModelViewSet

Tags: url, django-rest-framework

I have created an very simple API-REST that works fine, but now all the links are absoute urls and I want to translate to relative urls.

A resume of my configuration is:

**model.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializer.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','url','name')
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

As a aproach I tried overwritting the context of the ViewSet like this:

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': None}
```

With this now the url is printed with relative url, but if I navigate with a browser, the links dissapear and only appear as text, so I can`t click the differents elements.

Is neccesary to configure anything else for work the relative urls also in a browser?

Comment: In your post I can see `Environment` model and `User` model. Did you missed something?

Comment: Yeah is a mistake copying and paste code, really the unique model is User

Comment: You defined a field `url` in serializer and there is no reference to a model field or nothing. It raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the logic behind the `url` field?

Comment: The url is provided by default with the HyperlinkedModelSerializer, the unique thing that I'm doing is declaring this field in the output of the API, like I say at the begining the API works fine, the problem that I have is by default the links are created with full path and if I configure for create relative urls the href in the api web disappear so I can't click them with a browser

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in your view. According to the official [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#absolute-and-relative-urls) you have to pass the request to the serializer context like this
`context = {'request': request}`. This will solve the problem, although simply deleting the serializer context method, or returning `super()` in the method will also work. Here is a revised view :

```
    class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewset):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer
```